# What's the best way to save and retrieve data for a Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a small amount of data (~2kb string) I need to save and retrieve from a lambda function. What's the best way to do this?

I only need to write these values a couple of times a day but I need to retrieve them each time my Lambda function is called so it will be a lot of reads with just a couple writes.

I know my solutions are DynamoDB, S3 or ElasticCache. I also have seen SSM Parameter Store but I'm not clear if it's possible to write values or if this is a server just to read values.

I was hoping someone could advise on the best and most cost-effective approach for this in a Lambda Function.

Comment: What type of data? How big is it? Does the Lambda function always need to most recent version of it?

Comment: I edited my post. It's about a ~2kb string.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for you, here are some and the use of each.

**DynamoDb or RDS:**
These are database driven solutions, and come with their own services and components that need to be created in order to use them. The cost of these will scale depending on data volume, how much data comes in or goes out etc, and may not be suitable if you just want to store a couple of values infrequently (although you could do this in DynamoDB and it would be quite cheap).

**S3**
S3 is a great place to store objects / files. It is cheap, easy to use, and might be your best option. You could create / write to / update / delete a file in an S3 bucket from your lambda function. So after your function has completed, your data would remain in this file for use the next time around. You could store your data as files, configuration within files, and so on.

You've mentioned **SSM Paramater** store. This is usually used to store configuration values for your applications, servers or functions. This could be things like a database connection string, or the name or 'ARN' (AWS address for resources) for other services your solution interacts with. It is not typically used as a 'data store' for data to work with your application. Nor is ElasticCache, this is - as the name suggests a - a caching technology used to make access to data faster for web applications and so on. The benefit of storing configuration data for apps in SSM, is that they're available to all your solutions (e.g. a shared database connection string) and can be encrypted at rest as well for security.

Your best bet, if you're talking solely within AWS, is to use S3 to store objects / files and data. If you happen to store your data in JSON or CSV format, you can even query that information directly from the file(s) in S3 using services in AWS like S3 SELECT, or you could use Athena to create tables/schema based off your data in S3, and query it just like a SQL database!.

So, S3 is probably the best and most cost effective. Your other option could be to have your Lambda function write to the local file system (EBS for example) of an EC2 instance in your AWS environment. As EC2 instances are just virtual machines, they have file systems where you can store data and files in folders just like a normal computer. Your Lambda function could write data to this file system for storage or retrieval. Depending on what you want to *do* with your data, you could also submit it to a service like SQS, which is a message queue, and have that message queue process that data into another service.

There are lots of options in the AWS space, but to keep things simple and based on the very vague explanation you've provided, Amazon S3 would seem the best approach. Simple, easy to code against, and cost effective to write data to.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, since it's just a 2KB string and rarely changes, I would recommend using Systems Manager Parameter Store.

There are functions to Put and Get a parameter. It's just a **Key-Value store**, with the ability to use IAM to restrict which roles/users can access the data.

You can either retrieve the value every time the Lambda function executes or, if you're not concerned about getting the very latest value, it could be cached in the Lambda function upon first execution.